# MySQL + delete Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 Database DB1 and DB2.

Table1 from DB1 has column

id | name | roll | path

where
id is the primary key

Table2 from DB2 has column

name | email | creation_date

where
name is a primary key

'name' in Table1 is same as 'name' in Table2

rows in column one gets deleted by some server using web API.

I want to synchonize between Table1 of DB1 and Table2 of DB2 such that, 
when any rows gets deleted from Table1 corresponding row from Table2 also gets deleted.

How I can achieve this?

Any suggestion/links

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use replication on specific table

[MySQL manual : Replication Slave Options and Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table)

```
--replicate-do-table=db_name.tbl_name
```

Command-Line Format :   **--replicate-do-table=name**

Option-File Format  :   **replicate-do-table**

Permitted Values    :   (Type : string)

Tells the slave SQL thread to restrict replication to the specified table. To specify more than one table, use this option multiple times,

Answer (score 0):

Using ON DELETE CASCADE Option can achieve this